# How / can we ask about preparation for an expansion or new patch?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This concerns [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151566/what-should-i-do-with-my-excess-gold), but I think we can have a discussion more abstractly.

What are the restrictions on asking about preparation for future content?

In this case,  there are a limited number of acceptable answers (less than 10 ways to spend gold on D3).
The question is about current content, and not the content of the patch/expansion.
Other games, (such as apparently D2) have experienced a similar trend, so users can draw on experience to answer.

What are acceptable requirements to have a question about PREPARING for future content, or does this wholeheartedly fall under the 'no future content questions' rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Historically, these kinds of questions lead to speculation and guessing, which does not equate to good content and isn't generally very useful to our target user base.

The reason that questions about unreleased content are considered off topic on Arqade is because while in many instances there are developer announcements about features that are planned to appear in an expansion/update, these are subject to change outside of out control.

Additionally, once content is released, these questions become useless once the content is actually released, as the expansion/update in many cases changes the base game (for example, World of Warcraft expansions, League of Legends patches, etc).

There are plenty of resources on our meta that already discuss this topic at length, here are some for further reading:

- [Why are concrete questions about pre-orders off-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7072/why-are-concrete-questions-about-pre-orders-off-topic)
- [Are pre-order questions valid?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5358/are-pre-order-questions-valid)
- [When is a game publicly available?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)
- [How should I reword a question that has a canonical answer, but has been put on hold as speculative?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8014/52800)

Ultimately, **we cannot predict the intent of the developer** - what they say they're intending to do and what they're actually going to end up doing does not always align. Arqade is not a discussion forum and speculation about what might happen isn't the sort of thing we do. Arqade is the place for authoritative answers to problems you're actually facing in a game.

Comment: This feels a little different to me, though. It's not directly asking about the future content... it's asking about how to best manipulate the currently existing content to get maximum benefit when the future content hits. It still has a speculation element, but not JUST a speculation element. For instance, when a new WOW expansion hits that raises the level cap, there are probably certain things you can do to prepare for it that don't require knowing specific details of the expansion (like unload all your unbound max-level epics now, since they'll 99% likely be crap when the expansion hits)

Comment: The primary focus of the question mentioned by Bob2Chiv to me is "The new expansion might reduce the value of gold, what should I spend my gold on?". This is a very speculative question whose answer is in what will happen to the economy after the forthcoming expansion is released. This very much seems like a question about a future expansion to me.

Comment: @kalina You raise a pretty important point there: People "prepare for the change" *because* they want to be "ideal" when said change hits. So it most certainly *is* about "what is ideal after the change?", which is *pure* speculation.

Comment: I think Sterno raises a valid point though - with certain games that have already been through multiple expansion releases (like WoW) it's possible to make an educated guess on how the new expansion will affect the economy, the item scaling, etc and provide a genuinely useful answer. However in this case, Diablo 3 hasn't had an expansion yet, we don't know how this is going to affect these things other than the fact it will most likely have some affect - therefore we can't really answer it.

Comment: Do you want to be the person who tells somebody to sell all of their gear only to find out there is some previously unannounced upgrade mechanism for legendaries in the new expansion?

Comment: That could *always* happen, though, even when there *is* prior knowledge from other expansions. An expansion is supposed to be a *fundamental change* - we cannot predict that, and I very much doubt that we can give a sufficiently good estimate.

Comment: These are all very good points, and definitely gives me a new prospective on the question. Does the fact that there is a beta that is well documented of this content change your statement?

Comment: @Bob2Chiv Most of the argument in the comments is about whether or not answers would be based on the *existing content* or on *future content*. I come to the conclusion that it's very much about *future content*, in which case [this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5539/41081) applies.